# Titan: securing Solr (with basic auth) as an index backend?

Tags: java, solr, titan

I'm using Solr as an indexing backend for Titan, and have it working as long as I don't enable authentication in Solr. After adding basic auth, I am prompted in the browser to log in to see the solr interface, but nothing is added to Solr with basic auth on. How would I log in to Solr from Titan, preferably with the Titan configuration (something like index.search.solr.username)?

If it is possible with SolrCloud, I could also try that. I am using Solr because ElasticSearch and Titan have compatibility issues where Shield cannot secure ES and still work with Titan.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is here on Titan github issues page: https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/issues/1066